# What does "crs" mean in structural engineering / construction?

Tags: structural-engineering, foundations, pile-foundations

In the realm of structural engineering, construction, foundation design, what is "**crs**" when talking about piles/posts? Is it an abbreviation? Does it refer to some sort of size?

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"CRS" is an abreviation for "Centers".

So, for example the statement "Deck Joist @ 400mm crs" means "at 400mm centers", i.e. that the centreline of the joists should be 400mm apart.

If you were to measure the *gap* between the joists, it would be less than 400mm, due to the thickness of the joist itself.

Comment: Also, I have usually seen "centers" abbreviated to "cts". I wonder if this abbreviation is a regional thing?

Comment: @hazzey Could be due to "centres" vs "centers" spelling (in New Zealand).

Answer (score 3):

Does not apply to this example, but just for completeness: I've also seen CRS as an abbreviation for cold-rolled steel in a material callout in machine drawings, e.g. "1018 CRS".